# Unable to create a constant value of type 'EShop.ClassLibrary.ProductType'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this 2 class that product is related to ProductType but when use below code I see the following error.

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'EShop.ClassLibrary.ProductType'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

They are related on ProductType LinkProductTypeId

```
 public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType LinkProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string EngName { get; set; }
    public virtual RelatedProduct ProductRelated { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal BuyCost { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal SellCost { get; set; }
}
```

```
 public class ProductType
{
    public virtual int ProductTypeId { get; set; }//id in ef
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Runtime code is this:

```
 public static List<SelectListItem> GetProductSelectList()
    {
        ProductType type = _db.productType.Single(t => t.ProductTypeId == 1);
        List<Product> m = (_db.product.Where(r => r.LinkProductTypeId == type) ).ToList();//error line

        List<SelectListItem> sa = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Product item in m)
        {
            sa.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Name, Value = item.ProductID.ToString() });
        }

        return sa;
    }
```

Comment: A word of alert. When asking for help, you need to pass all information. For example, ""but it fails" do not tell "how it fails" nor WHERE it fails (which line throws the exception). Read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem you have to deal with it the following line of code:

```
List<Product> m = (_db.product.Where(r => r.LinkProductTypeId == type)).ToList();
```

As it seems there you try to get all the products whose `LinkProductTypeId` equals the `type`, you have get before. Probably you can't resolve using the equality operator the equality of those objects.

What I suggest is to use the `ProductTypeId` for doing so. In terms of code:

```
List<Product> m = (_db.product.Where(r => r.LinkProductTypeId.ProductTypeId == 
                                          type.ProductTypeId)).ToList();
```

If `ProductTypeId`  is unique for each `ProductType`, which it seems that is it is, then the above would do your job.

> Why the above works, while the previous it doesn't work?

The above works, because you just compare compare two integers, if they have the same value then the predicate in the `Where` returns `true` and the current item would be included to the list.

The previous it doesn't work, because `==` between two reference types is looking for referential equality and not for the corresponding fields of the objects have the same values.

Let that we have a class

```
public class Customer 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }      
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Then this console app

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var customerA = new Customer("firstname","lastname",22);
        var customerB = new Customer("firstname","lastname",22);

        Console.WriteLine(customerA==customerB);
    }
}
```

will output `false`, because despite the fact that the all the values of `customerA` and `customerB` have the same values, `customerA` and `customerB` are two different objects. Please have a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cP7xpX).